# IBM Db2 Warehouse on Cloud manage user access to schemas

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

When creating users in the DB2 console on IBM Cloud is there a way to resrtict user access to selected schema/s only?  I am running on the SMP Small version.

Comment: Different options exist, can be mixed depending on your security model and operational requirements.  This is a large topic. Refer to the Db2 documentation for details of `CREATE ROLE` and GRANT and REVOKE statements, and plan whether you will use ROLES or USERS/GROUPS or both.

Comment: thank you kind sir! you should have put that as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer an up it as well. Your suggestion actually solved a buttload of my problems! thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different options exist, can be mixed depending on your security model and operational requirements. This is a large topic. Refer to the Db2 documentation for details of CREATE ROLE and GRANT and REVOKE statements, and plan whether you will use ROLES or USERS/GROUPS or both